# Google Apps Script throws "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 13, file "Code")"

Tags: google-apps-script, server-error

I'm trying to migrate Google Drive files to new accounts in a new domain.  I thought I had finished my script, but when I tried to test it I keep getting this very unhelpful error.  Does anyone know what sorts of problems typically cause this error, or how to interpret it?  I've searched SO, but I did not find anything useful.

Here is my script:

```
function copyDrive() {


  var originFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(originFolderID);
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationID);

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastExecution = scriptProperties.getProperty('LAST_EXECUTION');
  if( lastExecution === null )
    lastExecution = '';

  var fileContinuationToken = scriptProperties.getProperty('FILE_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  var fileIterator = fileContinuationToken == null ?
    originFolder.getFiles() : DriveApp.continueFileIterator(fileContinuationToken);
  var folderContinuationToken = scriptProperties.getProperty('FOLDER_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  var folderIterator = folderContinuationToken == null ?
    originFolder.getFolders() : DriveApp.continueFolderIterator(folderContinuationToken);

  try { 
    var rootFileName;
    while(fileIterator.hasNext()) {
      var rootFile = fileIterator.next();
      var rootFileDateCreated = formatDate(rootFile.getDateCreated());
      if(rootFileDateCreated < lastExecution) {
        rootFileName = rootFile.getName();
        rootFile.makeCopy(rootFileName, destination);
      }
    }
    var folder = folderIterator.next();
    var folderDateCreated = formatDate(folder.getDateCreated());
    if(folderDateCreated < lastExecution) {
      var folderName = folder.getName();
      var folderCopy = folder.makeCopy(folderName, destination);
    }
    copyFiles(folder, folderCopy);
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }

  if(fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('FILE_CONTINUATION_TOKEN', fileIterator.getContinuationToken());
  } else {
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty('FILE_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  }
  if(folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('FOLDER_CONTINUATION_TOKEN', folderIterator.getContinuationToken());
  } else {
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty('FOLDER_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  }
  scriptProperties.setProperty('LAST_EXECUTION', formatDate(new Date()));

};

function formatDate(date) { return Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); };

function copyFiles(passedFolder, targetFolder) {
  var fileContents = passedFolder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var fileName;

  while(fileContents.hasNext()) {
    file = fileContents.next();
    fileName = file.getName();
    file.makeCopy(fileName, targetFolder);
  }
  copySubFolders(passedFolder, targetFolder);
};

function copySubFolders(passedFolder, targetFolder) {
  var subFolderContents = passedFolder.getFolders();
  var subFolder;
  var subFolderName;

  while(folderContents.hasNext()) {
    subFolder = subFolderContents.next();
    subFolderName = subFolder.getName();
    var subFolderCopy = targetFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFiles(subFolder, subFolderCopy);
  }
};
```

I get the error on this line:

```
  var fileIterator = fileContinuationToken == null ? originFolder.getFiles() : DriveApp.continueFileIterator(fileContinuationToken);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just comment that line that it is pointing to and check if it still erroring out. If that doesnot work try commenting each line and see if the error is really with this function or not. You could always use the debugger and execution transcript to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by manually deleting the script properties.  After doing that I don't get the error anymore, but the continuation token that's being saved at the end is the same as the one loaded at the beginning.